# What is the Java equivalent of C++'s templates?

Tags: java, c++, generics, templates

What is the Java equivalent of C++'s templates?

I know that there is an interface called Template. Is that related?

Comment: I tried to rephrase your question to make it more understandable. Feel free to roll back my changes if you feel it changed the question into something else.

Comment: @ jalf:hey by mistake i rolled back.. can u again make it more understable?

Comment: @girnie, I rolled it back to jalf's changes for you

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[Templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming#Templates_in_C.2B.2B) as in C++ do not exist in Java. The best approximation is [generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html).

One huge difference is that in C++ this is legal:

```
<typename T> T sum(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

There is no equivalent construct in Java. The best that you can say is

```
<T extends Something> T Sum(T a, T b) { return a.add(b); }
```

where `Something` has a method called `add`.

In C++, what happens is that the compiler creates a compiled version of the template for all instances of the template used in code. Thus if we have

```
int intResult = sum(5, 4);
double doubleResult = sum(5.0, 4.0);
```

then the C++ compiler will compile a version of `sum` for `int` and a version of `sum` for `double`.

In Java, there is the concept of [erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). What happens is that the compiler removes all references to the generic type parameters. The compiler creates only one compiled version of the code regardless of how many times it is used with different type parameters.

Other differences

- C++ does not allow bounding of type parameters whereas Java does
- C++ allows type parameters to be primitives whereas Java does not
- C++ allows templates [type parameters to have defaults](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/default_args_for_templ_params.htm) where Java does not
- C++ allows [template specialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_specialization) whereas Java does not
  And, as should be expected by this point, C++ style [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) is impossible with Java generics.
- Forget about seeing the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in Java
- [Policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) is impossible in Java

Comment: Your c++ example will fail to compile if you try to pass it a type that doesn't have addition defined. Same as your java example, with the method add. Your example does not illustrate template differences, but the lack of operator overloading in Java. Otherwise, good answer :)

Comment: @gnud: That's right, but there's a subtle difference. In C++ the template that I wrote above is legal without restriction on `T`; it's only if you try to use it with a type that doesn't have `+` defined will there be a failure. In Java, there is no equivalent. So in C++ you can say "define `sum` for anything that has `+`." In Java you can not say this; you can only specify that `T` extends `Something` that has an `add` method. Thus if you have a `U` that does not extend `Something` but it has an `add` method you can not use the above defined `sum` on instances of `U`.

Comment: C++ does sort of allow bounding of type parameters, but in a really roundabout way.  Basically if a template expansion fails for certain reasons it is removed from the list of candidate expansions.  This is called SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) in the C++ community.  You can use this to do compile time introspection on classes and expanded certain things one way and other things another.

Comment: C++ also allows non-type template parameters

Comment: @jason yes, in java you would have to provide an abstract interface, like Comparable

Comment: @Omnifarious: `boost::enable_if` FTW!

Comment: With concepts (c++20), bounding of type parameters is fairly natural, e.g. `template <typename T> void f(T x) requires std::derived_from<T, T_base> { }`.

Answer (score 9):

There are no real templates in Java. C++ templates are compile-time entities that are used to generate classes. At runtime, there is no trace of them.

In Java, there are parameterized types as part of a mechanism called generics. It serves a similar purpose, but is significantly different in how it operates and its implications. It has some representation at runtime, there are specific rules, etc.

Start by reading the [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), then read Bloch's Effective Java for a detailed description of the caveats if you want to be a "power user".

Comment: The first paragraph is probably the most concise explanation of templates I've seen. +1 for that alone. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are no templates in Java. The only thing that is comparable with templates are Java Generics.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/generics/

Answer (score 0):

Java has generics which are similar but not exactly the same as templates.  I don't know what the Template interface is but it has nothing to do with C++ templates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in template mechanism in java. In stead they have generics. Moreover, ides have something called code templates e.g. for [eclipse](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/useful-eclipse-code-templates).

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need templates in Java. Templates are mainly useful when you need to have completely different types as a parameter that you know nothing about. In Java, all objects are virtual and inherit from one root object, and primitive types are defined much more clearly and casts work in a more sensical manner so there's really no point to it.

You can get better performance with C++ style templates, but due to the way they generate much more code and the fast CPU speed outstrips data access speed more and more every year this is less and less the case, especially when it comes to objects as opposed to primitives.

Comment: @charles wrote "...they generate much more code...". That's an over-generalization. Every language feature can be misused somehow. If you know what you're doing you won't have problems with code bloat. In addition, the compiled C++ code isn't clogged with the amount of meta data that is required in Java to be "more dynamic". But I agree with your first sentence. You can get pretty far by using runtime polymorphism + garbage collection. Performance will just suck a little.

Comment: well, the only time they won't generate more code is if you only have one type used by a template and only have one object file using the template. I don't mean to say never use templates since C++ sort of forces you to, but they won't have as much performance improvement over Java as most people think and also add a lot of complication.

Comment: it depends on the field and your coding style, when you need to deal with some programs which mess up with a lot of primitive types like image processing + you need to inline a lof of "functor", template is a way to go.In the field of image processing, we always use more binary space to trade with speed.Besides, compile time polymorphism could lower the dependency since inheritance enforce very strong relationship within classes, I hate it when I don't need it, but java and other's OO only language force me to do it